# Google Test: Is it OK to abuse the comma operator to return values from ASSERT_ statements?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, macros, googletest

After some frustration using ASSERT_ statements in non-void functions, I discovered a workaround that works, but seems dubious.

I want to know if this is good practice or not.

Here's an example:

```
bool MyTest() {
    // ... code here
    ASSERT_TRUE(condition) << "Message", false;
    // ... more code
    return true;
}
```

This works because ASSERT_  ends up calling GTEST_FATAL_FAILURE_, which returns the result of calling a void function:

```
#define GTEST_FATAL_FAILURE_(message) \
  return GTEST_MESSAGE_(message, ::testing::TestPartResult::kFatalFailure)
```

Since I didn't see anything like this specified in the Google Test documentation, I'm wondering if I can depend on this implementation remaining as it is, or whether it may possibly change and break things later.

I'd appreciate any insight.  Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need cutom test function instead of standard gtest macro?

Comment: You would be using the macro for something that is not intended. There is no guarantee that the definition of the function doesn't change later causing your code to break. Moreover, you would make your code less readable. One would expect ASSERT statements to break the test. Using them in a function hurts your code's redability.

https://testing.googleblog.com/2019/12/testing-on-toilet-tests-too-dry-make.html

Comment: Isn't this what EXPECT_ macros are for?

Comment: Apologies for my mistaken answer earlier.  I misunderstood the question; I though you were just asking how to use a void-valued expression in a place that requires another type, and I forgot that ASSERT_* macros return from the current function.  In that case, yes, I think that the EXPECT_* macros are what you are after.  They'll immediately end the test if the condition fails.  Using a comma to subvert the return of the ASSERT_* would be confusing.  It definitely confused me anyway. : )